# To find the sum of rows based on some condition in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi i am not able to find sum of rows in this query -

The tables are as follows:

Master_Choicecode

```
ChoiceCode      MainCourseId    CourseLevelId    InstituteId
```

Master_MainCourse

```
MainCourseId     MainCourseName   CourseLevelId   CourseProgram
  11                x                1             abc
  12                y                2             xyz
```

Master_CourseLevel

```
CourseLevelId    CourseLevelName     
   1                deg
   2                Dip
```

Master_Institute

```
Instituteid     InstituteName    Statusid
  1001           Insti1          100
  1002           Insti2          200
```

Master_InstituteStatus

```
StatusId   StatusName
 100            Status1
 200            Status2
```

Now using all these tables i want to show this:

```
CourseProgram   CourseLevelName  Status1(from Master_InstituteStatus)  Status2(from Master_InstituteStatus) TotalInstitutes
abc             Deg          Count(status1institute)  Count(status2institute)             Total(status1+status2)
```

Now this is what i have tried:

```
SELECT B.CourseProgram,C.CourseLevelName,
sum(case when E.InstituteStatusName =' Status1' then 1 else 0 end )as     Status1,
sum(case when E.InstituteStatusName =' Status2' then 1 else 0  end ) as  Status2,
FROM Master_ChoiceCode A 
inner join Master_MainCourse B on A.MainCourseID=B.MainCourseID
inner join Master_CourseLevel C on A.CourseLevelID=C.CourseLevelID  
inner join  Master_Institute D on A.InstituteID=D.InstituteID
inner join Master_InstituteStatus1 E on D.InstituteStatusID1=E.InstituteStatusID
where B.CourseLevelID IN(1,2)
GROUP BY B.CourseProgram,A.CourseLevelID,C.CourseLevelName,E.InstituteStatusName
order by B.CourseProgram,C.CourseLevelName;
```

With this i get the output like this:

```
CourseProgram   CourseLevelName  Status1(from Master_InstituteStatus)     Status2(from Master_InstituteStatus)    
  abc              deg                10(count of status1)                 20(count of status2)
```

Please tell me how should i find the sum of Status1 column and Status2 column so that i can get the last column as Total_No_ of_institutes

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT B.CourseProgram,C.CourseLevelName,
sum(case when E.InstituteStatusName =' Status1' then 1 else 0 end )as     Status1,
sum(case when E.InstituteStatusName =' Status2' then 1 else 0  end ) as  Status2,
sum(case when E.InstituteStatusName IN (' Status1', ' Status2') then 1 else 0  end ) as  Total_No_of_institutes,

FROM Master_ChoiceCode A 
inner join Master_MainCourse B on A.MainCourseID=B.MainCourseID
inner join Master_CourseLevel C on A.CourseLevelID=C.CourseLevelID  
inner join  Master_Institute D on A.InstituteID=D.InstituteID
inner join Master_InstituteStatus1 E on D.InstituteStatusID1=E.InstituteStatusID
where B.CourseLevelID IN(1,2)
GROUP BY B.CourseProgram,A.CourseLevelID,C.CourseLevelName,E.InstituteStatusName
order by B.CourseProgram,C.CourseLevelName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT B.CourseProgram,C.CourseLevelName,
sum(case when E.StatusName=' Status1' then 1 else 0 end )as Status1,
sum(case when E.StatusName=' Status2' then 1 else 0  end ) as  Status2,
FROM Master_ChoiceCode A 
inner join Master_MainCourse B on A.MainCourseID=B.MainCourseID
inner join Master_CourseLevel C on A.CourseLevelID=C.CourseLevelID  
inner join  Master_Institute D on A.InstituteID=D.InstituteID
inner join Master_InstituteStatus1 E on D.InstituteStatusID1=E.InstituteStatusID
where B.CourseLevelID IN(1,2)
GROUP BY B.CourseProgram,A.CourseLevelID,C.CourseLevelName,E.InstituteStatusName
order by B.CourseProgram,C.CourseLevelName;
```